# Cannot cast PreferenceFragment into Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-preferences

I am creating an app with some fragments, and there is also a PreferenceFragment, which is accessible from "3 dots menu", like this:

[image]

and I am trying to inflating my Setting Fragment here:

```
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.dotsSettings:
            //here

            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

As I want inflate the preference fragment into the container of other fragments, the AS says that I can't cast PreferenceFragment into Fragment, is this way possible? Or any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the PreferenceFragment extends Fragment

```
class PreferenceFragment extends Fragment { }
```

and the Fragment being,

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
```